# Change position of tooltip on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tooltip

I'm using jQuery UI to create a tooltip for a search input field. I then want to position the tooltip according to the size of the browser window (top if less than 768px, left if more).

I initialise the tooltip with:

```
$('#search').tooltip({'placement':'top'});
```

Then I have this function to change the placement depending on the window size:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if ($(window).width < 768) {
        $("#damSearch").tooltip({'placement':'top'});
    } else {
        $("#damSearch").tooltip({'placement':'left'});
    }
}).trigger('resize');
```

For some reason it's not working. The tooltip initialises fine but when I resize the browser above 768px it still appears positioned to the top.

**[EDIT]**

I've been away for a few days and have just come back to try and resolve this problem.
I've installed Modernizr because I intend using it elsewhere on the site and so I thought I'd use Modernizr.mq to detect the window resizing. I also read elsewhere that the code to reposition the tooltip should be in its own self contained function, so this is the function:

```
function positionTooltip() {
    if (Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 768px)')) {
        $("#damSearch").tooltip({'placement':'left'});
    } else {
        $("#damSearch").tooltip({'placement':'bottom'});
    }
}
```

This is then followed in my Javascript file with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    positionTooltip();
    // Fire the function on page load

    $(window).resize(positionTooltip);
    // Fire function on window resize event
```

Unfortunately it's still not working correctly.
The tooltip appears correctly positioned when the page is first loaded, but if I then resize the browser the position is not updated. If I reload the page however the tooltip's position is changed accordingly.

It's as if the resize event is not triggering the function.

**[/EDIT]**

As ever all help and advice is greatly appreciated.
Tony.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the width function

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
```

notice the parentheses `()`

Comment: Thanks for your help PhilVarg but there was a typo in the code I posted. I had included the parentheses in my original code, but left them out when creating the post! I've updated my post to reflect changes I've made to try and (unsuccessfully) resolve the issue.